# jQuery to Wordpress - Uncaught errors driving me insane

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, wordpress

I recently finished a little application on Codepen and I decided to bring it over to my website, which is using Wordpress. I replaced all instances of $ with jQuery and updated the location of my JSON file, but I'm getting some issues in the console.

The program functions just fine - it's reaching the JSON file and pulling info from it - up until I click on a scale button and it stops dead. The first time, there's nothing in the console, but the second dead click will bring this up:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at ga.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ga (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at r.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.r.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at r (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

I'm getting a headache from this, I've put jQuery applications on this site before and had issues with it, but I was able to get the others going eventually...this time is different.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could take a look and see if they can spot the issue, I'm so frustrated with it now.

This is the original (functioning) codepen: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/NdLWJy
This is the transferred wordpress version: https://www.electricherald.com/guitar-scales-chart-application/

Here's the new jQuery (for comparison):

```
jQuery('.A, .As, .B, .C, .Cs, .D, .Ds, .E, .F, .Fs, .G, .Gs').hide();

jQuery.getJSON("https://www.electricherald.com/json/scalesDirSm.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  jQuery('.main-btn').on("click", function () {
    jQuery('#total-scale-men').empty()
    console.log("emptied total-scale-men");
    jQuery('.gcMen ul li button').css({'border' : '1px #666 solid',
   'color' : '#666'})
    jQuery('.scales-men').hide()
    jQuery('.scales-men').fadeIn()
    jQuery(this).css({'border' : '1px #cc4c4c solid',
   'color' : '#cc4c4c'})
        var scale = jQuery(this).data('scale')
        jQuery.each(data,function(i,data){
            if (scale == data.root) {
                jQuery('#total-scale-men').append('<button class="scale-btn" data-css="'+ data.CSS +'">' + data.scale + '</button>');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.scale-btn').on("click", function () {
    jQuery('.nt').hide()
    jQuery('.scales-men').hide()
    jQuery('.gcMen ul li button').css({'border' : '1px #666 solid','color' : '#666'})

      var css = jQuery(this).data('css')
      jQuery.each(data,function(i,data){
        var notes = ['.'+data.noteClass_1,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_2,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_3,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_4,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_5,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_6,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_7,
                     '.'+data.noteClass_8]
      if (css == data.CSS) {
      jQuery('#test').html(notes)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(1)').text(data.root)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(2)').text(data.scale)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(3)').text(data.structure)

        for(var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
        jQuery(notes[i]).fadeIn();
      }
      });
  })

    })
});
```

I'd really greatly appreciate some direction with this one, I'm really angry at wordpress right now. I wish I'd built the site myself at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce the error on codepen by switching to the version of jquery you are using on your production site[image]

So on your site you should upgrade to jquery 3.x

Comment: I thought about doing that while I was in bed last night actually, that's a good idea. I actually updated my jQuery file that the theme uses to the latest one, but for some reason it just doesn't work out - even after clearing cache etc. The theme calls for the file with the version in the link: jquery.js?ver=1.2.1 or something like that...I don't know if that's making a difference when the file itself contains the 3.1 version - I'll have to edit the WP theme innards if so -_-

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
    at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at a.fn.init.r.fn.init (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at a.fn.init (jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js:2)
    at r (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (scalesApp.js:43)

It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: if (css == data.CSS) {
      jQuery('#test').html(notes)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(1)').text(data.root)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(2)').text(data.scale)
        jQuery('#inf div:nth-child(3)').text(data.structure)

        for(var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
        jQuery(notes[i]).fadeIn();
      }

This is the issue. You can see on the link I provided to the website that I placed a #test div on top to show that the array 'notes' is being accessed properly - so I removed the last part of statement above and the error goes away but the text still won't show.

Comment: Nevermind all this, I fixed it finally. Wordpress is such a turd sometimes.